# How to use Spring to back Freemarker "?new" built in?

Tags: spring, freemarker

Currently we have a number of classes that extend `TemplateMethodModelEx` which we construct using Spring and then inject into the Freemarker `Configuration` as shared variables so they are available as functions to all of our templates.

However, it would be nicer to have more fine grained control and make these methods available on demand in individual templates.  One can instantiate them using the `?new` built in, but internally that uses the general Java reflection mechanism for instantiating the class, and these models need to be constructed via Spring to get their dependencies.

In a perfect world, I'd like to make it so that the `?new` built in use Spring to construct the class.  It looks like to do that I would need to find a way to overload `BeansWrapper.newInstance(Class, List)` to use Spring, but I'm unclear on the best way to accomplish that.

Note that we are currently using Freemarker 2.3.23

Comment: After thinking about this some more, I realized ?new requires a class, and it would also be nice to also be able to pass in a bean name, so I ended up just creating a TemplateMethodModelEx that takes a bean name/class and uses Spring to instantiate and return a new TemplateMethodModelEx .  I am still curious about the right way to take over the class construction though.

Comment: `BeansWrapper.newInstance` can be overridden by extending `DefaultObjectWrapper` (or `BeansWrapper`). Though I don't yet see that to be a good idea. `?new` meant to be just like Java's `new`. If you need something more sophisticated, sooner or later you will need some extra parameters, and perhaps no class name as in your case, and then the name "new" won't be a good fit anymore. But worse, you will confuse users when they look up `?new` in the Manual.

Comment: That is a good point @ddekany, I do wonder if it would be a useful extension point to allow plugging in an alternative TemplateModel creation mechanism (much like Struts2 has a pluggable ObjectFactory).

Comment: Well, as I said, my opinion is that `?new` should just do what it does (and also consider that many uses it in `#include`/`#import` to pull in directives/methods implemented in Java, so if suddenly `?new` can do some magical instead of the fixed thing... you get it). Or what do you mean?

Comment: No, I agree overloading ?new might be confusing, but I can't be the only one looking for an easy way to have a different method construction mechanism.  Was thinking could be a new built in that would default to the same behavior as ?new, but could alternatively pass its String argument to a user provided factory that would support an alternative construction mechanism.

Comment: I'm not yet feeling this. How would that look? Is this so similar in all the frameworks? Is this in the scope of the FreeMarker core? FreeMarker usually tries not to interfere with maters that aren't about templating itself. The idea is that frameworks can provide their own way of doing things without competing with a "standard" solution (as with JSP). (Yes, `freemarker.ext.servlet` violates that principle, but that's an extension that should have been a separate jar really...)

Comment: Well, here is a little more background about why we ended up here.  So, there are a number of methods the backend developers would like to provide to the UI developers (who work primarily in Freemarker) that cross functionality, but require a number of Spring dependencies.  The current way we achieve this is to pass a Map of name/TemplateMethodModelEx pairs via Spring to where we build the Configuration where they are then set as shared vars.  The thing I didn't love about this was that it was at the global Configuration level, and that is why I was looking for per template level solution.

Comment: I should mention that the solution I ultimately landed on was similar to how  STATICS and ENUMS are handled, where I created a psuedo-TemplateHashModel that looks at the key and returns a TemplateMethodModelEx constructed/looked up in Spring. So I could write something like: <#local getUser=METHODS["getUserMethodBean"]/>

Comment: Or rather just call it directly as `METHODS.getUserMethodBean()`.

Comment: True, which is very cool.  METHODS also supports the class name though, so I don't think METHODS.com.myco.UserMethodBean() would work alas (vs METHODS["com.myco.UserMethodBean"])

Comment: Right, if the key contains dots, then you have to use either `[]` or `METHODS.com\.myco\.UserMethodBean()`, which is not much nicer though.